# // error: Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function (anonymous function)

Tags: javascript

In the code below  i am not able to instantiate b as new a()  but able to do so as new f(). My conclusion is for new to work the object has to be a direct/immediate  descendant of function.  Is that accurate?  I am relatively new to javascript and am struggling to get a fundamental understanding of the language.  thanks,

```js
var f = new Function();
console.log("Prototype of f:" + f.prototype);
console.log("Constructor of f:" + f.constructor);
console.log("Prototype Link of f:" + f.__proto__);
if (f instanceof Function) console.log("f isa Function");


function A() {}
console.log("Prototype of A:" + A.prototype);
console.log("Constructor of A:" + A.constructor);
console.log("Prototype Link of A:" + A.__proto__);

var a = new A();
console.log("Prototype of a:" + a.prototype);
console.log("Constructor of a:" + a.constructor);
console.log("Prototype Link of a:" + a.__proto__);
if (a instanceof Function) console.log("a isa Function");
if (a instanceof A) console.log("a isa A");


var b = new f();
console.log("Prototype of b:" + b.prototype);
console.log("Constructor of b:" + b.constructor);
console.log("Prototype Link of b:" + b.__proto__);

 //  b = new a();
 // error: Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function (anonymous function)
```

Comment: It's because `A` is `instanceof Function and Object`, whereas `a` is `instanceof A and Object` - also have a look on http://metadea.de/V/

Comment: `f` is a function. `a` is not. `new` can only be used on functions.

Comment: if(A instanceof Function) console.log("A isa Function"); //true   if(a instanceof A) console.log("a isa A"); // true BUT if(a instanceof Function) console.log("a isa Function");  // FALSE?  I am confused.

Comment: also Object instanceof Function; // true  so if a is instanceof Object then doesn't it follow  a is instanceof Function?  I am missing something fundamental.

Comment: You have a Function Object, called A. You get a new thing, instanceof A Object.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on that...

```
var f = new Function();
console.log("Prototype of f:" + f.prototype);
console.log("Constructor of f:" + f.constructor);
console.log("Prototype Link of f:" + f.__proto__);
if (f instanceof Function) console.log("f instanceof Function");
if (f instanceof Object) console.log("f instanceof Object");

function A() {}
console.log("Prototype of A:" + A.prototype);
console.log("Constructor of A:" + A.constructor);
console.log("Prototype Link of A:" + A.__proto__);
if (A instanceof Function) console.log("A instanceof Function");
if (A instanceof Object) console.log("A instanceof Object");

var a = new A();
console.log("Prototype of a:" + a.prototype);
console.log("Constructor of a:" + a.constructor);
console.log("Prototype Link of a:" + a.__proto__);
if (a instanceof A) console.log("a instanceof A");
if (a instanceof Object) console.log("a instanceof Object");
```

Answer (score 0):

> The [Function constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) creates a new Function object. In JavaScript
>   every function is actually a Function object.

```
var f = new Function();//f is a function and not an normal object
var b = new f();//work expected as f is a function
```

**Reason why new a() will not work**

```
function A() {}//A is function
var a = new A();//a is not a function rather an object
var b = new a();//throw error as 'new' expect function
```

**[new operator:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)** 
The new operator expects a [constructor function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_a_constructor_function).

```
var a = new foo[([arguments])]//foo must be a function.
```

When the code new foo(...) is executed, the following things happen:

1. A new object is created, inheriting from foo.prototype.
2. The constructor function foo is called with the specified arguments and `this` bound to the newly created object. new foo is equivalent to new foo(), i.e. if no argument list is specified, foo is called without arguments.
3. The object returned by the constructor function becomes the result of the whole new expression. If the constructor function doesn't explicitly return an object, the object created in step 1 is used instead. (Normally constructors don't return a value, but they can choose to do so if they want to override the normal object creation process.)
   e.g

   ```
   function f() {
       this.y = 50;//will be overridden due to below return statement
       return function () {
           this.x = 5;
       }
   }
   var b = new f();//b is a function as f() is returning a function and hence it will override the normal function creation
   alert(b.y);//undefined as y is no more property of instance b as function constructer has a return statement returning object(function object in this case)
   var c = new b(); 
   alert(c.x);//c.x = 5;
   ```

Comment: Thank you Amitesh.  this is Helpful.  I am curious if there is a way to check the [[Construct]] property on an object.  Just like typeof obj test the [[Call]] property?

Comment: Yes. You can use instanceof operator. Visit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof

Comment: Amitest, Bergi answered this correctly, here is his reply:No, the only thing you can do is something like try { new x; return true } catch (e) { return e instanceof TypeError } –  Bergi yesterday